# o2cb thinks ocfs2 cluster is still online, and refuses to shut down

Tags: linux, ocfs2

I have a handful of OpenSuSE 11.2 servers that utilize OCFS2 volumes.  I've noticed that o2cb can't figure out when the OCFS2 cluster is actually mounted.  For example, when I try to shutdown o2cb, after stopping OCSF2, o2cb refuses to shutdown because it thinks OCFS2 is still up!

After stopping OCFS2 I try to stop o2cb...

```
hamguy:/dev/disk/by-label # /etc/init.d/o2cb stop
Stopping O2CB cluster ocfs2: Failed
Unable to stop cluster as heartbeat region still active
```

So I check the status...

```
hamguy:/dev/disk/by-label # /etc/init.d/o2cb status
Driver for "configfs": Loaded
Filesystem "configfs": Mounted
Stack glue driver: Loaded
Stack plugin "o2cb": Loaded
Driver for "ocfs2_dlmfs": Loaded
Filesystem "ocfs2_dlmfs": Mounted
Checking O2CB cluster ocfs2: Online
Heartbeat dead threshold = 31
Network idle timeout: 30000
Network keepalive delay: 2000
Network reconnect delay: 2000
Checking O2CB heartbeat: Active
```

And double check OCFS2...

```
hamguy:/dev/disk/by-label # /etc/init.d/ocfs2 status
Configured OCFS2 mountpoints:  /u/conf /u/logs /u/backup /u/client /u/data /u/mdata
```

OCFS2 is clearly down, while o2cb clearly thinks otherwise.

The versions of OCFS2 and o2cb are...

```
kendall@hamguy:~> rpm -qa |grep ocfs2
ocfs2console-1.4.1-25.6.x86_64
ocfs2-tools-o2cb-1.4.1-25.6.x86_64
ocfs2-tools-1.4.1-25.6.x86_64

kendall@hamguy:~> rpm -qa |grep o2cb
ocfs2-tools-o2cb-1.4.1-25.6.x86_64
```

What causes this, and is there a way around it?  If I try to reboot the machine, it will just sit there forever until your physically power cycle it.  That obviously is a bit of a problem.

Any insight is appreciated, thank you.

Kendall

Comment: Just to verify, does `mount | grep ocfs` and `cat /proc/mounts | grep ocfs` indicate that the OS thinks anything is mounted via ocfs?  And what OCFS processes are still showing from `ps -ef | grep ocfs`?

Comment: I'll try to check that as well, tonight, when I can do it without impacting service.  I know I checked 'mount |grep ocfs2' but I didn't copy the output and don't remember what it said.

Answer (score 2):

```
umount -l /dev/device 
/etc/init.d/o2cb offline ocfs2
```

make sure that Checking O2CB heartbeat: is INACTIVE when you do `/etc/init.d/o2cb status`

if is doesnt change to INACTIVE then remove all its entries from `/etc/fstab` and reboot.

Check status again after reboot , if it is INACTIVE then unload and re-enable  the nodes using:

```
/etc/init.d/o2cb unload
/etc/init.d/o2cb enable
```

POINT is the nodes must all be in INACTIVE state before joinging them all to the same heartbeat

IT WORKED FOR ME